# Programmatically display the image button in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I get my expected output displayed as below, but how do I know which button the user clicked?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqzhY.png)

Below here is my code in asp.net, or maybe I should use asp:Repeater to do this ?

```
    <table style="width: auto">
     

        <% int count = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < (No_of_Bed / 2); i++){%>

        <tr>

        <% for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) { %>
                <td>
                    Position <%=count %> :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="bed" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img.png" />
                </td>
            
        <% count++; }%>

           </tr>
         <%   } %>
            
        <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use commandargument or commandname to pass the value to the backend.

Comment: CommandName="<%=count %>", I make it like this but it cannot get the variable's value

Comment: How are you getting the variable's value? I do not see a onclick event in your button.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it. And i did this in the backend:-

ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)(sender);
string clicked = btn.CommandArgument;
testing.Text = clicked;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is an example of how to do it.

```
<table style="width: auto">
     

        <% int count = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < (No_of_Bed / 2); i++){%>

        <tr>

        <% for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) { %>
                <td>
                    Position <%=count %> :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="bed" runat="server" OnClick="bed_Click" CommandName='Parse here the value you want' ImageUrl="~/img.png" />
                </td>
            
        <% count++; }%>

           </tr>
         <%   } %>
            
        <tr>
</table>
```

You can use by the way CommandName and CommandArgument, it does not really matter.
Backend:

```
 protected void bed_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;

            string commandname = btn.CommandName;
        }
```

Comment: is it possible to pass dynamically value in CommandName/ CommandArgument ? For example I want to set the "Count" variable as the CommandArgument. I make it like this  CommandName="<%=count%>", but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

for that, you need a different Id for every Image buttons,
not sure if it is useful for your Requirement, but you can try using this

Change ID="bed_0" -> For Image one ,
ID="bed_1" So on

For that, you can use int j

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i could'nt pass int j into the id